# LUIS ERROR: Sorry, my bot code is having an issue

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I created new LUIS bot from azure portal, and tested in "Test in Web Chat", it was working fine.

I created new app in luis.ai portal, with few indents and entities, also trained and published. Now updated the application id and and app key under Application settings for Luis APPId and LUIS API Key respectively in Azure portal, after that if i type anything in "Test in web chat" I'm consistently getting this below message

> "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue."

If anyone solved this plz let me know, I'm not sure what mistake am making here

Comment: Is this V3 or V4?

Comment: it is V3.0 LUIS bot template

Answer (score 0):

I tried recreating the scenario and it worked for me.The error message which you are getting is the default bot notification of an unhandled exception. I would suggest you do the following steps:

1.Download the bot code and run it locally to check for errors.

2.Try debugging the bot using [ngrok](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/).

You can use the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-general-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to troubleshoot the issue.